# Visualizing Subplot Overlap

Tags: visualisation

I have a bit of trouble visualizing my data.
I have a dataset with 60 minutes of seismic signals and i determined the signal source areas. My goal now is to find out how the results change using different window sizes.

Example: The dataset is divided into 5 minute windows and the signal source areas are calculated for each window (i.e. each window is treated as its own dataset). I then overlap the results of each window to see which signal areas are detected using this window size. The localization count shows how often the areas overlap.

I did this for every window size and the end result looks as follows:
[image]
Now i want to merge these subplots into one plot, showing which signal source areas appear in which window size. So basically it should show the areas that the window sizes have in common and which are different. And you should be able to recognize which window size(s) each source area belongs to.
I don't know how to show this in a clear, well-arranged way.

Maybe i'm using a wrong approach, i feel like this could be handled very well with some spatial technique. I did some research but i couldn't find anything that could be applicable.

The localization counts can be omitted, it's just about the area shapes now.